# Filling out a comment form and submitting with python & selenium

Tags: python, forms, selenium

I have a web page that I am trying to post a comment with, but I can't seem to get the text to show up in the comment box. Here is the code from the site:

```
<form id="commentForm" class="comment_form" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <p class="post-error" style="display: none;">There was a problem posting your comment, please try again.</p>
    <textarea placeholder="Leave a comment..." name="comment" id="commentBox" class="commentBox" onkeyup="limitTextReverse(jQuery('.commentBox'),jQuery('.myCount'), 140);" onkeydown="limitTextReverse(jQuery('.commentBox'),jQuery('.myCount'), 140);"></textarea>
    <span class="button grey btn-submit" class="track-click" data-track="checkin_page" data-href=":comment/post" href="#">Post<input type="submit" value="Post" /></span>
    <span class="comment-loading" style="display: none;"></span>
    <span class="counter"><abbr class="myCount">0</abbr>/140</span>
    <input type="hidden" name="checkin" value="123456789" />
  </form>
```

and here is what I have so far:

```
box = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "comment_form")))
box.click()
```

however, when I try to send_keys to it, it kind of freaks out and nothing goes in. Any thoughts on how to actually get text into the comments box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what might be happening is you are clicking on the `form` element, but you are not clicking on the actual comment box. You don't want to type into the upper level `form` element, you want to type into the `textarea`.

You can select an element by id, then type into it:

`elem = driver.find_element_by_id("commentBox")`

`elem.send_keys("This is a comment I'd like to write!")`

[The Selenium Getting Started Guide](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/getting-started.html)